# Installing Adaptec 2906 SCSI card on Vista machine

Tags: windows-vista, scsi, hostadapter

I'm having some trouble installing an Adaptec 2960 SCSI card using the Add Hardware wizard on this Vista machine.  The machine isn't autodetecting the card, but when I attempt to point the wizard to the driver files from the manufacturer's website like so: [image]
the wizard just returns to the "Select the device" window with no devices listed.  I've tried selecting both .inf files in the driver folder with the same result.  I know I've had this SCSI card working on the machine in the past, so I'm not sure what has gone wrong this time. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: 1) The 2906 is a PCI card. It *should* be detected, even if only as unknown hardware. 2) The driver for vista 32 bits can be found here: ( http://www.adaptec.com/en-us/speed/scsi/windows/aic78xx_aic78u2_vista_x86_v605456_exe.htm ). Do these also fail for your card? If you run 64 bit you might be out of luck. quating Adaptec: "There will be no support for x64 Editions "

Comment: @Hennes Yup, those are the driver files I'm trying to use - I'm on Vista 32 bit so they should work.  Next step I think is to try unseating the card and/or moving PCI slots, maybe a bad connection?  There's also the unfortunate possibility that the card itself is damaged.